# Codeigniter 3.1 - Get database error number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql Stored procedure that is called when a user should be deleted. Procedure signals an SQL state and throws error when someone tries to delete the row of Administrator Account. My Code in procedure is -

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Adminstrator cannot be deleted';
```

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1. I want to catch this error message WITH its sql state in my code. 
I looked into following links but no help -

1) [CodeIgniter - how to catch DB errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors)

2) [Database Error Handling problem in CodeIngniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418254/database-error-handling-problem-in-codeingniter)

What I observed was that there was a method `$this->db->_error_number();` that could be used to get error number/sql state, but this is deprecated in latest version.

I wanted to know is there any way in CodeIgniter to get the SQL State if the database error occurs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209332/codeigniter-how-to-check-if-there-is-anything-in-the-validation-error-array  |  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors

Comment: I already visited these, didn't work in latest version

Answer (score 3):

The function you mention has been deprecated:

> Replaced the `_error_message()` and `_error_number()` methods with `error()` - which returns an array containing the last database error code and message."

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html?highlight=_error_number#version-3-0-0

See https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors for details.

Comment: CI's error() is empty during SQLSTATE 45000. I don't understand this behavior. Looks like it only shows error generated by my MySQL but not coming from user-defined errors from stored procedures and triggers.